# How do I get rid of gray site container in genesis framework?

Tags: css, wordpress, genesis

Below is my code to get rid of the gray borders surrounding the content in genesis framework.

```
.site-container {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1140px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

I'm not sure why this isn't making a change in my website.
[image]

Still looks exactly the same.

Comment: Adding a link to a test / staging / live site, until the question is answered, would really help those trying to provide you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

set background color

```
.site-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1140px;
   padding: 0 30px;
}
```

if not solved could be the grey background is related to the parent of you site_container ..

check for backgrond  in body and html   or in parent of you container

and set these

```
 background-color: #fff;
```